# Double integral over arrays w/ scipy.trapz (no analytic function)

Tags: python, math, scipy, numerical-integration

I must integrate two arrays (f(x) and g(x+r)) and a function `wfg(r)` = [triangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) with the following integral:

[image]

with the analytic forms of f(x) and g(x) unknown.

My initial attempt was to integrate f(x)g(x+r) w.r.t dx using `scipy.trapz` and then multiply this result by the integral of `wfg(r)` w.r.t dr:

```
for ri in r:
    if np.abs(ri) < l:
        term1 = lambda ri, l : (1 - np.abs(ri)/l) 
        tmp1 += integrate.quad(term1, r[-1],r[0] ,args = (l))[0]
    else:
        tmp1 += 0

return np.abs(tmp1 * integrate.trapz(gpeaks1*gpeaks2_r,x_fg))
```

where the integral of `wfg(r) = tmp1`, `f(x) = gpeaks1`, and `g(x+r) = gpeaks2`.

But this doesn't seem correct mathematically. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what I understood is this (correct me if I'm wrong):

What you have:

- Array `x_fg` with shape `(x_size, 1)`
- Array `r_fg` with shape `(1, r_size)`
- Array `gpeaks1[i] = f(x_fg[i])` with shape `(x_size, 1)`
- Array `gpeaks2[i, j] = g(x_fg[i] + r_fg[j])` with shape `(x_size, r_size)`

As an intermediate result, you also have:

- Array `h[j] = ∫_i gpeaks1[i] * gpeaks2[i, j]` with shape `(1, r_size)`

  - Computed with `h = integrate.trapz(gpeaks1 * gpeaks2, x_fg, axis=-2)`

About `w_fg`: following your code to the letter, `w_fg` is a **number**, not an **array**.
But your question seems to indicate `w_fg` is a weight function and, as such, should be represented by an array.

So, my fist question is "what is `w_fg`?"

Assuming:

- Array `w_fg[j] = w(r[j])` with shape `(1, r_size)`

My second question is "what do you want to calculate?"

If it's `∫_j w_fg[j] h[j]` then just do `integrate.trapz(w_fg * h)`.

---

## Previous answer, which doesn't actually answer the question

So, given two 1D arrays `f` and `g` representing functions,
you want the array `h` which represents `h(r)=∫f(x)g(x+r)dx`.

You can totally do this with `scipy.trapz`, but integrals of the form
`h(r)=∫f(x)g(x+r)dx` can be much more easily computed with [`np.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html)
or an equivalent in scipy.

The most efficient way is by using FFTs. I don't have time right now to write an explanation, but I'll add one later.

I suggest you read about [convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and [cross-correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).

Comment: It isn't the cross-correlation integral (`h(r)=∫f(x)g(x+r)dx`) that gives difficulties, it is the weighting factor tacked on that makes the integral more complex. In my code, `h(r) = integrate.trapz(gpeaks1*gpeaks2_r,x_fg)`.

Comment: @Slayre with `h(r)` in hands, `integral w(r)h(r) dr` is just `trapz(w * h)`

Comment: @Slayre Maybe I understood wrong. I followed the picture and didn’t pay much attention to you code. Sorry about that. How many dimensions does `gpeaks2` have? Is it two, like `gpeaks[i,j]=g(x[i]+r[j])`?

Comment: you understood correctly. All arrays are of similar shape (gpeaks, gpeaks2_r, r, x_fg). What I have above is very different from `integral w(r)h(r) dr`. I idiotically treated the dbl integral as a product of two integrals.